# I want to get the number of tasks per minute from array in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

The array (arrival_time) contains the arrival rate timestamp in minutes. I would like to have a moving window (in minutes) in order to be able to get hours, days, etc.

I would also like to calculate the mean of the y-values. I am having issues with the plot...

```
    dput(arrival_time)

    arrival_time <-
    c(39883.2110833341, 39886.1476833341, 39887.0075666675, 39887.0075666675, 
39887.0075666675, 39887.0075666675, 39887.0075666675, 39887.0075666675, 
39887.0075833341, 39887.0076166675, 39887.0076166675, 39887.0076166675, 
39887.0076166675, 39887.0076166675, 39887.0076166675, 39887.0076166675, 
39888.9650000008, 39888.9650000008, 39890.6224666675, 39890.6592833341, 
39891.1546833341, 39891.1546833341, 39891.1546833341, 39891.1546833341, 
39891.1547000008, 39891.1547000008, 39891.1547000008, 39891.1547000008, 
39891.1547166675, 39891.9282000008, 39891.9282000008, 39891.9282166675, 
39891.9282166675, 39891.9282333341, 39891.9286166675, 39891.9286166675, 
39891.9286333341, 39891.9286333341, 39891.9286333341, 39891.9286500008, 
39891.9286500008, 39893.0087500008, 39893.0087666675, 39893.0087666675, 
39893.0087666675, 39893.0087666675, 39893.0087666675, 39893.0087833341, 
39893.0088000008, 39895.3851833341, 39895.4266166675, 39898.7485500008, 
39898.8688333341, 39898.9459000008, 39899.3301833341, 39899.3301833341, 
39899.3301833341, 39899.3302000008, 39899.3302000008, 39899.3302000008, 
39900.6571833341, 39901.6217833341, 39901.6217833341, 39901.6217833341, 
39901.6218000008, 39901.6218000008, 39901.6218000008, 39901.6218000008, 
39903.1350500008, 39903.2219666675, 39904.9844500008, 39905.4003166675, 
39908.9786333341, 39909.1339666675, 39909.9115000008, 39910.1579666675, 
39910.5364333341, 39910.5790000008, 39917.1312333341, 39917.1411000008, 
39917.1610166675, 39917.1610333341, 39918.6737000008, 39918.6737166675, 
39918.6737166675, 39918.6737333341, 39920.2628000008, 39920.5762000008, 
39921.2869833341, 39925.3144833341, 39925.3144833341, 39925.8580500008, 
39925.8580500008, 39928.7718166675, 39928.7718166675, 39928.7718333341, 
39928.7718333341, 39929.1229666675, 39930.1203000008, 39931.0687166675, 
39932.3121000008, 39932.3121000008, 39932.3121166675, 39932.3121166675, 
39932.3121166675, 39932.3121166675, 39932.3121333341, 39933.0955833341, 
39933.0956000008, 39934.7180333341, 39934.7180333341, 39935.7146666675, 
39937.0611000008, 39937.0611166675, 39937.0611333341, 39937.0611500008, 
39937.0611500008, 39937.0623166675, 39937.0623166675)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried and sample data? Please edit **the question** with the code you ran and the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (Note: `df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: Those are minutes? It's not an object of class `POSIXct`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas yes, is the timestamp of the task

Comment: Your data spans almost 3 years (85111937 minutes or 985.0919 days). Do you really want a graph by the minute?

Comment: @RuiBarradas Sorry, the timestamp values were in millisecond, instead of minutes. I just uploaded the new correct data in minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this point into the direction you want to go?

```
library(tidyverse)

arrival_time <- as_tibble(arrival_time)
ggplot(arrival_time, aes(value)) + 
    geom_histogram(bins = 1000)
```

Comment: It looks good. But, what is the meaning of "bins = 1000"? I dont get it.

Comment: ```bins = 1000``` tells geom_histogram to put the input data into 1000 bins - I've used 1000 because it was near to the 985 days that your input data spans. If you play around a bit with that parameter, you should get the idea - see also [https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_histogram.html](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_histogram.html) and here for examples [https://statisticsglobe.com/ggplot2-histogram-in-r-geom_histogram-function](https://statisticsglobe.com/ggplot2-histogram-in-r-geom_histogram-function)